# How can i get all instances of app services in Azure using c#?

Tags: c#

Is there sample code that will get all app services in a resourcegroup in Azure and then all instances of these app services , using c# ?

Answer (score 0):

To get all instances of App Services in Azure using C#, you can use the Azure SDK for .NET. Here are the steps to do this:

Make sure you have the Azure SDK installed in your C# project. You can do this via NuGet or Visual Studio package manager.
Authenticate with your Azure account. You can use a service principal, managed identity, or interactive login. Here's an example using an interactive login:

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromUser("your-username", "your-password", "your-tenant-id", AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
var azure = Azure.Configure().Authenticate(credentials).WithDefaultSubscription();

var appServices = azure.AppServices.List();

foreach (var appService in appServices)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"App Service Name: {appService.Name}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Resource Group: {appService.ResourceGroupName}");
    // Add more properties you want to display
}
```

Comment: it says AzureCredentialsFactory does not contain a definition of FromUser and IAppServiceManager does not contain a definition of List in the line azure.appservices.List() ?

Comment: cant i authenticate using client id , secret , tenant id ?